# can not read last column data from excel file

Tags: java, excel, swing, filereader, xssf

I am reading data from Excel file for the salary generation in that column is empcode, emp_name,working_days,overtime_hour when reading data from excel file i am read only first three column means i am read only working days i can not read overtime_hour please suggest what i wrong.i tried bellow code

```
public class csv_Upload extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {

        public static JFrame f;
        JPanel panel;
        Connection con = null;
        JButton b1,b2,b3,b4;
          int Status=0;
        JTextField txt1;
        int company_id1=0;
        JLabel l1;
        Font g,g1;
          JFileChooser fc;
          JTextArea log;
          File file1 ;
          String str;
          JComboBox jb1;
        public csv_Upload() 
        {
            panel=(JPanel)getContentPane();
            panel.setLayout(null);
            g=new Font("Georgia",Font.BOLD,22);
            g1=new Font("Georgia",Font.BOLD,15);
            panel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 230 , 255));    
            l1=new JLabel("Upload Excel File");
            l1.setBounds(200, 50, 400, 30);
            l1.setFont(g);
            l1.setForeground(Color.RED);
            panel.add(l1);
            jb1=LoadCombobox();
            jb1.setBounds(200, 100, 180,30);
            jb1. addItem("Select Company");
            panel.add(jb1);
            txt1=new JTextField();
            txt1.setBounds(540, 150,200,40);
            panel.add(txt1);
            fc = new JFileChooser();
            b1=new JButton("Browse File");
            b1.setBounds(30, 150,200,40);
            b1.setFont(g1);
            b1.setForeground(Color.RED);
            panel.add(b1);
            b2=new JButton("Upload File");
            b2.setBounds(240, 150,200,40);
            b2.setForeground(Color.RED);
            b2.setFont(g1);
            panel.add(b2);
            ImageIcon img=new ImageIcon("calender.png");
            b3=new JButton(img);
            b3.setBounds(460, 150,50,30);
            b3.setForeground(Color.RED);
            b3.setFont(g1);
            panel.add(b3);
            b1.addActionListener(this);
            b2.addActionListener(this);
            b3.addActionListener(this);
            jb1.addItemListener(new company_events());
   }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
             if (e.getSource() == b1) {
                  int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(csv_Upload.this);

                  if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                 file1 = fc.getSelectedFile();
                 str=String.valueOf(file1);
                    System.out.println("file fath"+file1);
                  } else {
                  }
    } 
             if(e.getSource()==b2)
             {


                 if(!(txt1.getText().isEmpty())&&company_id1!=0)
                 {
                 try
                    {

                        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(str));
                        System.out.println("action performed in file"+file);

                        //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
                        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

                        //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
                        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                        //Iterate through each rows one by one
                        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
                        {
                            Row row = rowIterator.next();
                            int a=0;
                            int emp_code1=0;
                            int emp_id = 0;
                            double working_days=0,Over_timehour = 0;
                            Tax_Calculation tax=new Tax_Calculation();
                            //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                            {
                                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                                //Check the cell type and format accordingly

                                switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                                {


                                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                        if(a==0)
                                        {
                                            emp_code1=(int) cell.getNumericCellValue();
                                            System.out.println("empcode"+emp_code1);
                                        }
                                        if(a==2)
                                        {
                                            working_days=cell.getNumericCellValue();
                                            System.out.println("working days"+working_days);
                                        }
                                        if(a==3)
                                        {
                                            Over_timehour=cell.getNumericCellValue();
                                            System.out.println("ot hour"+   Over_timehour);
                                        }
                                        a++;

                                    break;
                                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
    //                                  System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
    //                                  a++;
                                        break;
                                }
    //                          System.out.println("record is find");
    //                          System.out.println("value is"+cell.getColumnIndex());
                            }
                            System.out.println("");
                            System.out.println("new rows");
                            }
                         file.close();
                    } 


                    catch (Exception e1) 
                    {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if(Status>0)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Salary is generated");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Salary is not Generated");
                    }
             }

                 else
                 {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Select Comapny name and Date ");
                 }


             }
             if(e.getSource().equals(b3))
                {
                txt1.setText(new DatePicker(f).setPickedDate());
                }
              }

        public JComboBox<String> LoadCombobox()
        {
            PreparedStatement st=null;
            ResultSet res=null;

            try {
                con = DbmsConnection.getConnection();
                    jb1=new JComboBox<String>();

                    String query="select * from company_details";
                    st =con.prepareStatement(query);
                    res=st.executeQuery();
                    jb1.addItem("Please Select Company");
                    while(res.next())
                        {
                            if(res.getString(6).equalsIgnoreCase("Active"))
                            {
                                jb1.addItem(res.getString(2));
                            }
                        }
                }
            catch (SQLException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            finally
            {
                try
                    {
                        st.close();
                        res.close();
                        con.close();
                    }
                catch(SQLException ed)
                    {
                        ed.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
            return jb1;
        }

        class company_events implements ItemListener
        {
    PreparedStatement stmt=null;
    ResultSet res=null;

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

                con=DbmsConnection.getConnection();

                if(e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                {
                    System.out.println("selected company is"+String.valueOf(jb1.getSelectedItem()));
                    try
                    {
                        stmt=con.prepareStatement("select company_id from company_details where company_name=?");
                        stmt.setString(1, String.valueOf(jb1.getSelectedItem()));
                        res=stmt.executeQuery();
                        while(res.next())
                        {
                            company_id1=res.getInt(1);
                        }

                    }catch (Exception e5) {
                        e5.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        try {
                            stmt.close();
                            res.close();
                        } catch (SQLException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }


            }

        }


        public static void main(String []s)
            {
                 f=new csv_Upload();

                f.setVisible(true);
                f.setSize(750,500);
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
    }
```

Comment: unrelated: a) don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, ever - that's the exclusive responsibility of the LayoutManager. b) please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that column 1, employee name, is non-numeric. Thus your `a` is not incremented for that column and is never equal to 3. You should be observing that the value printed out for "working days" is actually the overtime hours value in the spreadsheet.

One solution would be to use [`cell.getColumnIndex()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getColumnIndex%28%29) instead of trying to manually calculate the column.